# How to add a HtmlPrefix to Views Using MVC Actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following action to call the Multiple partial Views in a Single page.

```
public ActionResult AddDetail(string Key)
{
    var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData)
            {
                TemplateInfo = new System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo
                {
                    HtmlFieldPrefix = string.Format("{0}", key)
                }
            };
    return View(key);
 }

 [View]
 @model Customer
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Name)
```

The above code gives me the html rendered as

```
<input type="text" name="Name"/>
```

But, I wants to have

```
<input type="text" name="Customer.Name" />
```

If I pass the `AddDetail("Customer")` action.

I don't know how to get the `ViewContext` and append the `Prefix` to the Views.

Could someone please help me to add a prefix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :)

```
public ActionResult AddDetail(string Key)
{
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = string.Format("{0}", key)
    return View(key);
}
```